# shiftRows is not working for sharepoint files, its work for local file

Tags: java, apache-poi

In the Excel sheet file I checked there is no formula, then also I am getting the below error in java and I am using POI 3.9 jar

```
System.out.println("==========");
sheet.shiftRows(1, lastcolumn,1);    
System.out.println("========");
```

**Console Output**

```
Error :: Unused input [[Address]] after attempting to parse the formula [[1]!tbl_Denka[Address]]
```

Comment: From my side I checked there is no formula but then also getting error for formula I think, so could you so kind to know me how can I remove formula and then what should I have to do by which the code will run

Comment: [Apache POI 3.9 was released in 2012, almost a decade ago! What happens when you upgrade to something vaguely recent](http://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.9)?